Which of X and Y came into use earlier/first?

(1) Do you know which of "reprove" and "tell off" came into use
earlier?
(2) Do you know which of "reprove" and "tell off" came into use
first?

[my sentences]
Which sentence sounds idiomatic to native speakers of English? If neither sentence is natural, please let me know.

I'm happy with both, but would probably pick the second version.

I thought that "earlier" was better for two choices and that "first" was the only choice for more than two choices (e.g., Which of X, Y, and Z came into use first?). Thank you very much, JamesK.

"First" is fine with two things; it's not a superlative (earliest is a superlative and wouldn't work with two things).
